# Why do the views not move?

Tags: java, android, constraints

[this is the picture after i edit comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IMxk.jpg)Why do the views not move?

[image]

I get an error with the title :  This view is not constrained. It only has design time positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints, I tried with infer Constraints, but it did not work

Comment: The concept of ConstraintLayout is for not working with fixed DP.
So you need to learn Constrains. Like to put image on center use 
`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`
        `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` 

`app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`
       `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

In yout `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply `Clear all constraints`

[image]

2. Move Image.
3. Apply `Infer Constraints`

[image]

Comment: Move not work? Or image view ? Please share your xml

Comment: yeah sure  i edit comment and added a picture